# Launching jar file without terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have exported my Java project from Eclipse as "Runnable JAR file" with "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". When I try to launch it by double-clicking, nothing happens just the file flashes. When I try to run it from terminal like `java -jar Main.jar` it works fine.

Main.java

```
class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

I have also extracted the jar file to check the `MANIFEST.MF` file after seeing some stackoverflow answers

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Main
```

Java Version

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

OS

```
OS X El Capitain
Version 10.11.13
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works fine when you execute it by double clicking on it. But since this program is very short, it prints fast "Hello World" and is closed again. This makes you think nothing happened. Add in the last line of your code

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

to make it run for longer time and try again.

Comment: Nothing happens.The file just flashes and that's it. Terminal is not launching by the way if I completely quit the app.(Same result if I launched the terminal myself and trying to launch jar by double-clicking).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you double-click the jar file, the OS only launches a terminal for the lifetime of the app. Since yours is only one line and terminates immediately, the terminal also goes away immediately.

If you would like you can have your program hang after finishing executing with something like this:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
while(true) {
    synchronized (Main.class) {
        try {
            Main.class.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Which will just wait indefinitely until the user terminates the program manually.

Comment: Nothing happens.The file just flashes and that's it. Terminal is not launching by the way if I completely quit the app.(Same result if I  launched the terminal myself and trying to launch jar by double-clicking).